# How to deny a group to a subsite

Tags: security

I'm using SharePoint 2013

I would to grant acces to a subsite by a specific Active Directory group.
And i want to deny all other groups.

So the group that's allowed is able to acces the subsite and other groups don't.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your parent site have a group A which shouldn't have permission to your subsite, the first thing you need to do is *stop inheriting permissions* on your subsite. Site Actions > Site Permissions:

[image: Chose site permission]

Then select *Stop inheriting permissions*:

[image: Stop inheriting button]

And you'll get a warning you need to accept:

[image: Stop inheriting permission warning]

When these steps are done, you can safely remove the group that should not have permission to your subsite.

Comment: All my domain users have read rights on "Specify web application user policy" under security in the administrator server farm.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint's security model is deny all, allow select. Therefore, you can manage the permissions on the site and specify who you want to have access, and if someone is not listed, they won't have access. There is no specific deny option.

If you need assistance in actually walking through how to add a group. Reply and we'll get you the steps.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, for your reply can u hand me out the steps. That would be very helpful!

Comment: Go to the Settings Icon (gear at top right) > Site Settings. Click Site Permissions under Users and Permissions (top left).Click Grant Permissions in the ribbon to add your AD group. Check off existing groups and click Remove User Permissions to remove unwanted access.

Comment: It doesn't work. If iI logon with another user i can still acces the subsite. My domain users have read rights on the site collection maybe something you would like to know

Comment: How do the domain users have read rights? Where is that specified?

Comment: Yes i would like to see the steps. Very kind of you!

Comment: I listed the steps above in my comment